# Internal Server Error occuring When hosting PHP Version Upgrading from 5.2.x to 5.3.x

Tags: php, server

When I upgrade **PHP** version 5.2.x to 5.3.x on my windows server I started getting a Internal Server error code 500.

How can I get rid of from this error?

Comment: first check your Apache log and search the cause or internal server error

Answer (score 0):

your apache log, as mentioned, and your windows events log will help finding the problem. My first guess would be some incompatibility with php.exe and some dlls required by extensions, but it could be any number of things.

Running php.exe on command line also might show you the error.